Best way to substantially prune Oleanders
We have a pair of Oleander bushes which we have allowed to get quite large to cover our garage from the street.  It's time to repaint the house, and thus time to pay the piper for letting them get this large.
I have heard Oleander can be pruned to the ground and regrow successfully, and have done so on another bush which regrew back perfectly.  Of course, that's a sample size of 1.  Is there a more healthy way to make space for a painter behind these bushes, or is trimming them all the way down the best way?
Included are two pictures, in case the particular way we let it grow affects the answer.



Why do you feel it's all or nothing and can't prune 2' off each branch?

Depending where is the trunk, you may also just bind the branches, so you get space: very flexible plant. OTOH if you are painting, maybe you do not want it (with the wind) to scratch your new painted wall. If it growth easily as you write, prune as much you like.

I am no expert in pruning oleander, but when you're disposing of the waste, DO NOT BURN IT - the smoke is toxic and can cause illness or death.
